# How do I get a random line from a file and send it as a discord bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm new to python and I'm trying to get a discord bot to send a random line from a text file. So far i have this code, but it wont send when i send the command in the server.

```
import os
import discord
import requests
import random

from discord.ext import commands
client = discord.Client()
 

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('online {0.user}'.format(client))

bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "$");

@bot.command(name='filetxt')

async def filetxtgetter(ctx):
  lines = open('file.txt').read().splitlines()
  file = random.choice(lines)
  await ctx.send(file)


client.run(os.environ['token'])
```

Comment: Code is looking correct. But process may be silently failed because of exception (for example if you don't have `file.txt`). Try to simplify function: add only `await ctx.send('hard coded string')` and check is code working without file reading. If yes then problem is somewhere inside file reading piece

Comment: You're running `client`, however the decorator for the command is `@bot.command()`...

Answer (score 0):

```py
@bot.command()
async def filetxtgetter(ctx):
    f=open('file.txt')
    lines=f.readlines()

    value = random.choice(lines)
    random_line = (value.removesuffix('\n'))

    await ctx.send(random_line)
```

This should solve your question.